# Deleting all same values from Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

I have one generic list which contains some string value. Sometimes the values will be repeat. And I have to delete the specific values from the List Collection. I tried the following code.

```
List<string> postalCodes = new List<string> { "A1B", "A2B", "A3B","A2B" };
     string currentPostalCode = "A2B";
     postalCodes.RemoveAt(postalCodes.IndexOf(currentPostalCode));
```

But this code removing the item from the position 1, but not from 3. How can I delete from the both positions? Please hep me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.RemoveAll` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
postalCodes.RemoveAll(c => c == currentPostalCode);
```

If you want to use `RemoveAt` you have to do it in a loop:

```
int index;
while((index = postalCodes.IndexOf(currentPostalCode)) != -1)
{
    postalCodes.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion , you can also use `Where` to get your result like

```
List<string> postalCodes = new List<string> { "A1B", "A2B", "A3B", "A2B" };
string currentPostalCode = "A2B";
postalCodes = postalCodes.Where(f => f != currentPostalCode).ToList<string>();
```